# Git local server does not store my code

Tags: git, windows-server-2008

I have a little network at work with a few computers and a server, I created a bare repository on the server and cloned it from 3 computers.

I can clone/pull/push from computers, it works nice, but the project is not stored on the server and I understood that it should.

Where could it be stored? How can I have it on server too? any suggestion?

Comment: Can you push a changeset from one computer to the master repository and then pull that changeset to another computer?

Comment: Do you understand what a bare repository is?

Comment: @John yes, I can.

Comment: @heavyd yes, `.git` directory exists at server and have some other directories

Comment: @heavyd I understood that `bare` is to share a server but I guess the project have to be stored somewhere different to my local computers. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Andres A bare repository has no working copy. That is why it _seems_ that it is not "there" on the server. But is is indeed on the server. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to push/pull/clone it.

Comment: @RolandSmith I got it, thank you very much. My problem now is **show the historical** information on windows as _instaweb_ does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can push from one computer and pull to another computer, then your project is being stored in the Git repository on the server. You may not understand what that repository is supposed to look like, since it is not human readable in the same way a CVS or RCS repository is, but rest assured, it is there.

Comment: So, how can I see it as github? It is ok for me but my boss want to see something XD

Comment: You need to find an appropriate Apache (or web-server-of-your-choice) module that will make it available through a web interface.

Answer (score 1):

A bare repository has no working copy. That is why it seems that it is not "there" on the server. But is is indeed on the server. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to push/pull/clone it.

To show the historical information for that bare repo, you have to change directory to the bare repo and run a `git log` command. E.g. like this:

```
git log --graph --date-order --decorate --all --stat --no-color
```

It shouldn't be too difficult to capture this output and make a webpage out of it.

**Edit:**

Instaweb is a Bourne Shell script that also calls Perl and uses some Perl modules. It will not work on windows out-of-the-box. The same goes for [gitweb](http://repo.or.cz/w/alt-git.git?a=blob_plain;f=gitweb/INSTALL) itself which is a Perl script.

By installing the appropriate software, it should be possible to get gitweb to work on Windows but it will probably be a *lot* of work.

Git is native to Linux/UNIX and Windows doesn't come with the infrastructure that Linux/UNIX users take for granted. A lot of the [web interfaces](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb) for git are built for UNIX-like operating systems and depend on the tools that are generally available on those platforms.

There are relatively few frontends for the Microsoft stack. One is [WebGitNet](https://github.com/otac0n/WebGitNet/). Another is [GitStack](http://gitstack.com/). [Gitblit](http://gitblit.com/) is based on Java. Have a look at those.

Comment: I have used git log but I want to have something graphically, I tried to used **instaweb** on windows but I couldn't

Comment: @Andres: See updated answer.